# ion-select popover is not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Ionic-2 `ion-select` with popover is not working, but it works with `action-sheet` interface. The code is simple. I don't want those `ok` and `cancel` buttons.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>
        Selection Label
    </ion-label>

    <ion-select interface="popover">
        <ion-option selected>
            option1
        </ion-option>
        <ion-option>
            option2
        </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

**Ionic Info**

[image: my_ionic_info]

**popover**

[image: wrong-popover]

**action-sheet**

[image: correct-action-sheet]

Comment: Can you add the "simple code" because it is that code that adds the buttons. If you are creating select options in an alert then you need to use `this.alertCtrl.create();` with `alert.addInput({` and define your content in the component file, not the view

Comment: @arkade thanks for the response. i already put my code. you want me to put .ts file? well i added an AlertController extra only.

Comment: Add output of `ionic info`.

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa u can check my ionic info.its latest.

Comment: 3.5.3 is latest. For popover to work  just make "ionic-angular": "3.1.0" in `package.json` and run `npm install`. And try  `<ion-select interface="popover">`.

Comment: In your answer u have said that 3.1.0 is enough??

Comment: Yes, but you are using 3.0.1. Check your `ionic info` output - `ionic framework: ionic-angular 3.0.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `interface="popover"` as a property, `ionic-angular` version should be `3.1.0` or later.

Have a look at [3.1.0 changelog.](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#310-2017-04-26)

Comment: Although this does allow for a tag attribute to be added to the `ion-select` in the view this still does not allow for structural changes of the pop over like the removal of buttons

Comment: @arkade, It was not, check 2.0.0 released documentation http://ionicframework.com/docs/2.0.0/api/components/select/Select/

Comment: Not even in 3.0.0 http://ionicframework.com/docs/3.0.0/api/components/select/Select/

Comment: Check `Input Properties` not the demo.

Comment: If you want more info then go through this issue- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11407

Comment: It definitely was, i was implementing custom alert selects in ionic 2, but NOT as an input property, in the code behind manipulating properties on the `alertCtrl.create()` instance method options. You are thinking about this from a select view point of view and I am approaching it from alert creation point of view

Comment: It will be great if you can share some working code with ionic 2 and `ion-select`, or make a plunker.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/ check the section under "Alert Inputs" , that has been available since ionic 2 release. Just change the member inputs to "radio"

Comment: Question is clearly about `ion-select` i guess. Why don't you answer this question with alertCtrl.create()?

Comment: The question was actually about removing the buttons from the pop over - "I don't want those ok and cancel buttons" - which can be done if you decide to approach the problem from creating an alert that holds the select and not from a view based approach. and i am waiting for the OP to rely to a comment so that i can correctly answer his question